# Recomendation about Dell BIOS

Tags: dell, bios

I have a dell notebook inspiron 7460, that i bought two years ago. It came with windows but i erase the disk and put ubuntu. Im having some error with PCIe bus, that the only solution i read is tu put a parameter in the GRUB, that only dont show me that error, but not fix it. 
An actulization in the bios, may help? and if that, i think that the dell bios that i can download is for windows, so i need to install windows, update bios, and the come back to ubuntu?

Im new with this, so all information is good.

THX

Comment: that sounds unlike dell, they're usuall vey supportive of linux. you can contact their tech support I'm sure that this windows app is just an added layer over drivers and BIOS. tech support may be able to provide you the BIOS directly (which itself is agnostic of the OS on your hard drives, normally the BIOS update process goes like this : put the BIOS file on a FAT or FAT32 usb key of small size, boot to the bios configuration and select upgrade BIOS, it will do the rest.

Comment: Many newer Dell can directly update UEFI from Linux. UEFI/BIOS updates brand model list  for Dell with (uefi >= 0.6.2 & dell >= 0.7.3) 
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist

Comment: Was easier than i thought.

Problem solve!

THX!